# Java can't find text file in resource folder

Tags: java, resources, text-files, filepath, project-structure

I cannot seem to get Java to detect my text file. It keeps giving me a `FileNotFoundException()` I have been able to get it to find PNG and TTF files before, but I am not sure if there is something special I need to do to get it to find text files in a resource folder.

I am using Eclipse 2018-19 (4.9.0) with OpenJDK 11.

How can I make my program manage to find and utilize this text file?

**MCV Example:**

```
public static main(String[] args) {
   generateHumanName();
}

/**
 * Generates a male "human-ish" name from a text file of syllables.
 * @return String The male human name.
 */
private static String generateHumanName() {
   try {
      FileReader("/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt/");
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
      return null; // never called
}
```

**Exception Received:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../res/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at mcve.MCVE.generateHumanName(MCVE.java:21)
    at mcve.MCVE.main(MCVE.java:12)
```

**My File Path:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting this file in a resource folder (`res`): this is different than browsing for a file on the local file system (see below):

You need to use `MCV.class.getResourceAsStream("/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt")`:

```
try (InputStream is = MCVE.class.getResourceAsStream("/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt")) {
  if (null == is) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt");
  }
  try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    // do stuff here
  }
}
```

I won't delve too much on `getResourceAsStream`, [the javadoc will do better explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-), but:

1. It may return `null` if the resource does not exists. You may need to move the test outside the try with resources.
2. Eclipse copies any non java file into the output folder (`bin` by default).
3. The forward slash at the end of your code is wrong. Java probably tries to read a directory.
4. If you don't put a forward slash before the path (`/text`), it will be relative to the class (and package) on which you invoke the `getResourceAsStream` method.

Alternatively, if you want to read the file at some random location, you should pass it (eg: configure Eclipse to execute your program with some args) to your program and read it:

```
public static main(String[] args) {
   if (args.length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("missing path");
   generateHumanName(args[0]);
}

/**
 * Generates a male "human-ish" name from a text file of syllables.
 * @return String The male human name.
 */
private static String generateHumanName(String path) {
  try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(path)) {

  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null; // never called
}
```

Otherwise, you must move the `text` folder to the root of your project (where the `res` folder is), refresh your project, and use `text/male_human_name_syllables.txt` (because that is an absolute path).

The `res/text/male_human_name_syllables.txt` would probably work (because it executes from the root of the project).